# Hamiltonian and Gradient System Phase Planes and Level Curves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given a function $H(x,y)=ysin(x)$ which is Hamiltonian.  I want to sketh the phase portrait and level curves for the Hamiltonian system as well as the corresponding gradient system.
Then the system is $\\ x'=\partial H/\partial y=sin(x)=P(x,y), \\ y'=- \partial H/\partial x=y*cos(x)=Q(x,y)$

and the orthogonal gradient systems is: $\\
x'=Q(x,y)=y*cos(x), \\
y'=-P(x,y)=-sin(x)$.

I can plot the phase planes for these systems easily.  The level curves of the Hamiltonian are also easily generated.  However, I'm a little confused when I plot the level curves of the gradient system.  I know the gradient is normal to the level curves but can I explicitly solve for a function for the gradient system? If $\\
x'=y*cos(x)=\partial G/\partial y , \\
y'=-sin(x)=- \partial G/\partial x$

Then I can integrate both of these and get $G(x,y)=1/2y^2cos(x)-cos(x)$.  Is this an okay method?

Comment: Maybe your confusion is terminological. Your "orthogonal gradient system" is just gradient of $H$, meaning $x'=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}$, $y'=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}$, and indeed is orthogonal to level sets of $H$. Such a system is not Hamiltonian for any $G$, because it is not area preserving. You can see that there is no $G$ that solves the equations you write $
x'=y*cos(x)=\partial G/\partial y , 
y'=-sin(x)=- \partial G/\partial x$ since the mixed partials $\partial^2 G/\partial y \partial x$ and $\partial^2 G/\partial x \partial y$ would not be equal.